# JavaScript Mini-Max Sum - Challenge from HackerRank website

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Here is the Challenge:

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/mini-max-sum/problem

Despite my answer is returning the same number that matches the expected result, I have done something wrong because my answer has been rejected. 
How can I solve it?

Here is the solution I had tried:

```
function miniMaxSum(arr) {   

  var arrClone1 = arr.slice() 
  var arrClone2 = arr.slice() 

  var arrMinor = arrClone1.sort(function(a, b){return a - b;})
  arrMinor.pop()

  var arrMajor = arrClone2.sort(function(a, b){return b - a;})
  arrMajor.pop()

  function getSum(a, b) {
    return a + b;
  }

  var result1 = arrMinor.reduce(getSum) 
  var result2 = arrMajor.reduce(getSum)    

  console.log(`${result1} ${result2}`) // it is returning: 10 14
```

Comment: The code you posted worked perfectly for me on HackerRank. (I pasted the body of your function just below where it said, "Write your code here.")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. I noticed that it was mandatory to name the function argument as 'input' instead of 'arr'. That's why the answer was rejected by the HackerRank platform despite the code returned the right result in my editor, NOT in the HackerRank platform. If you do this simply adjustment, it works in the HackerRank platform too.

Just like that:

```
function miniMaxSum(input) {   //'input' NOT 'arr'    
  var arrClone1 = input.slice()   //'input' NOT 'arr'
  var arrClone2 = input.slice()   //'input' NOT 'arr'

//... rest of the code omitted
```

Answer (score 11):

I think the solution should be easier:

```
function miniMaxSum(arr) {
    let sum = arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
    let maxVal = Math.max(...arr);
    let minVal = Math.min(...arr);
    console.log((sum - maxVal) + ' ' + (sum - minVal));
}
```

Comment: How you can see in my answer, it only works if you named the parameter as 'input' instead of 'arr' because the argument passed in the hacker rank platform is named las 'input'.

Answer (score 2):

```
function miniMaxSum(arr) {
// Write your code here
    let sum=arr.reduce((a,b)=>{
        return a+b;
    });
    const min=sum-Math.max(...arr);
    const max=sum-Math.min(...arr);

    console.log(min+" "+max);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

my solution:

```
let sumValue = arr.reduce((a, b) => {
  return a + b;
});

const min = sumValue - Math.max(...arr);
const max = sumValue - Math.min(...arr);
const result =  `${min} ${max}`

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more procedural solution to the problem.

```
function miniMaxSum(arr) {
  let sum_min = 0
  let sum_max = 0
  let min_val = arr[0]
  let max_val = arr[0]
  let sum = 0

  for(let index = 0; index < arr.length; index += 1){
    if(arr[index] > max_val) {
      max_val = arr[index]
    }
    if(arr[index] < min_val){
      min_val = arr[index]
    }
    sum = sum +  arr[index]
  }
  sum_min = sum - max_val
  sum_max = sum - min_val

  console.log(sum_min, sum_max)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution, I hope it works for you

```js
function miniMaxSum(arr) {
    // Write your code here
    const max = arr.sort((a,b) => b-a).slice(0,4).reduce((a,b)=> a+b,0)
    const min = arr.sort((a,b) => b-a).reverse().slice(0,4).reduce((a,b)=> a+b,0)
    
    console.log(min,max)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got it right. The only "problem" is, that you're doing a Java or C++ coding challenge. (That's why they're mentioning the 32 bit integer).
The input shouldn't be an array but "A single line of five space-separated integers."

Comment: Thank you but what is the best way to do that?

Comment: @claudiobitar `'1 2 3 4 5'.split(' ').map(x => parseInt(x))`

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution...

```
function miniMaxSum(arr) {

let minValue = 0, maxValue = 0, minIndex = 0, maxIndex = 0, minSum = 0, maxSum = 0;
minValue = Math.min(...arr);
maxValue = Math.max(...arr);
minIndex = arr.indexOf(minValue);
maxIndex = arr.indexOf(maxValue);

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if (minIndex != i) {
        maxSum += arr[i];
    }
    if (maxIndex != i) {
        minSum += arr[i];
    }
}
   console.log(minSum, maxSum);
 }
 miniMaxSum([1,2,3,4,5]);
```

[Click Here to RUN](https://repl.it/@jaymanale/minMaxSumjs)

Answer (score 0):

Using .reduce:

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

function miniMaxSum(arr) {
   const res = arr.sort((a,b) => a-b).reduce((prev, cur, i) => {
      if(i!=0) ( prev.max=prev.max+cur || cur);
      if(i!=arr.length-1) ( prev.min=prev.min+cur || cur);
      return prev;
   }, [{max:0},{min:0}]);
   console.log(res.min || 0, res.max || 0);
}

miniMaxSum(arr) // 10 14
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works for all cases:

```js
function miniMaxSum(arr) {
   let c = arr.sort();   
   let a = c.slice(0,4)
   let b = c.slice(1,5)
   console.log(a.reduce((p,n)=>p+n,0),b.reduce((p,n)=>p+n,0))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution !

```
const numbers = arr.slice('').sort();

  let min = 0;
  let max = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    if (i < 4) {
      min = min + numbers[i];
    }
    if (i > 0 && i < 5) {
      max += numbers[i];
    }
  }

  console.log(`${min} ${max}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let numbers = arr.slice('').sort();
    let maxScore = 0;
    let minScore = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i < numbers.length - 1; i++) {
        minScore += numbers[i];
    };
    for(let j = 1; j < numbers.length; j++) {
        maxScore += numbers[j];
    };
    console.log(`${minScore} ${maxScore}`);
```

Comment: Please add a description of your question, what are you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

```
function miniMaxSum(input) {
    let minElem = 0, maxElem = 0, sum = 0;

    minElem = input[0];
    maxElem = minElem;
    sum = minElem;

    for (let i = 1; i < input.length; i++) {
        sum += input[i];
        if (input[i] < minElem) {
            minElem = input[i];
        }

        if (input[i] > maxElem) {
            maxElem = input[i];
        }
    }

    let minresult = sum - maxElem;
    let maxresult = sum - minElem;
    console.log(minresult + " " + maxresult);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function miniMaxSum(arr) {
    let sortarr = arr.sort();
    let maxSum = 0;
    let minSum = 0;
    for (let i=0 ; i < arr.length - 1; i++ ){
        minSum += sortarr[i];
    }
    for (let j=arr.length - 1; j > 0; j-- ){
        maxSum += sortarr[j];
    }
    console.log(minSum + ' ' + maxSum);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

guys. Just sharing my solution!

```
function miniMaxSum(input) {
    
    input.sort((a,b) => a-b)
    let min = 0, max = 0;
    for(let i=0; i < input.length; i++)
    {
        min += input[i]
        max += input[i] 
    }
    
    console.log((min - input[input.length -1]) + ' ' + (max - input[0]))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution --> This will handle duplicate and float values as well
Check the live demo below:

```js
function miniMaxSum(arr) {
    let tempArr=[];
    var sum = arr.reduce((acc,cur)=>acc+cur);
    arr.map((val)=>{        
        tempArr.push(Number(sum-val));
    });
    
    // unique values only
    tempArr = [...new Set(tempArr)];
    
    console.log(`${Math.min.apply(null,tempArr)} ${Math.max.apply(null,tempArr)}`);
}

miniMaxSum([7,69,2,203,894]);
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my solution

```js
function miniMaxSum(arr) {
    // Write your code here
    var sums = [];
    for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        var num = arr.shift();
        var sum = arr.reduce(function(acc, val) { return acc + val; }, 0);
        sums.push(sum);
        arr.push(num)
    }  
  console.log(Math.min(...sums) + " " + Math.max(...sums));  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function miniMaxSum(arr) {
    let arrayMin = arr.slice() //new array for minimum
    let arrayMax = arr.slice() //new array for maximum
    
    let small = arrayMin.sort((a,b) => {return a - b}) //sort number small to big
    let big = arrayMax.sort((a,b) => {return a - b}) //sort number small to big
    
    function maxsum (a,b){return a + b} // that's function for calculate all numbers
    
    let min = small.pop() //remove last element
    let max = big.shift() //remove first element
    
    let mins = arrayMin.reduce(maxsum) //apply maxsum function to array 
    let maxs = arrayMax.reduce(maxsum) //apply maxsum function to array 
    
    console.log(`${mins} ${maxs}`)
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

code worked for me is as below:

```
function miniMaxSum(arr) {
    // Write your code here
    let min = Math.min(...arr);
    let max = Math.max(...arr);
    let arrExceptMin, arrExceptMax;
    let allEqual = arr.every(val => val === arr[0]);     
    if(allEqual) {
        return console.log(sum(arr.slice(1)) + ' ' + sum(arr.slice(1)));
    }
    if(min) {
        arrExceptMin = arr.filter(val => val !== min); 
    }
    if(max) {
        arrExceptMax = arr.filter(val => val !== max);
    } 
    return console.log(sum(arrExceptMax) + ' ' + sum(arrExceptMin));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple Solution (I hope), there was not any problem with 'arr' argument with me.

```
function miniMaxSum(arr) {
    // Write your code here
    let a=0, b=0;
    arr.sort();
    for(let i=0; i<4; i++) {
        a+=arr[i];
        b+=arr[i+1];
    }
    console.log(a,b)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can shorten the code

```
function miniMaxSum(arr) {
// Write your code here
arr.sort((a,b) => a-b)
let min= 0, max = 0;
for(let i = 0; i < arr.length-1 ; i++){
    min += arr[i];
}
for(let j = 1; j < arr.length; j++){
    max += arr[j];
}
console.log(min,max);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Here's a single loop variant.

```js
function miniMaxSum(arr) {
    let min = 0
    let max = 0
    
    let sum = 0
    
    for (const n of arr) {
        sum += n
        
        if (!min || min > n) {
            min = n
            continue
        }
        
        if (max < n) {
            max = n
        }
    }
    
    console.log(sum - max, sum - min)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function miniMaxSum(arr) {
    let arrMin = [].concat(arr).sort()
    let arrMax = [].concat(arr).sort()

    arrMin.pop();
    arrMax.shift();

    let arrMinReduced = arrMin.reduce((prev, curr) =>  prev + curr)
    let arrMaxReduced = arrMax.reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr)

    console.log(arrMinReduced, arrMaxReduced)
}

miniMaxSum([1,2,3,4,5])
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses only **single loop** and also no utility functions.
code is pretty much self-explanatory.

```
function miniMaxSum(arr) {
    // Write your code here
    const total = arr[0] + arr[1] + arr[2] + arr[3] + arr[4];
    let max, min;
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        // Add all elements and subtract one element so that we sum of 4 items only
        let sum = total - arr[i];

        // Sets min & max both equal to sum on first iteration 
        if (max === undefined && min === undefined) {
            max = sum;
            min = sum; `enter code here`
        } else if (max < sum) {
            max = sum
        } else if (min > sum) {
            min = sum
        }
    }
    console.log(min, max)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let len = arr.length;
let smallest = arr[0];
let largest = arr[0];
let minSum = 0;
let maxSum = 0;

function minMax(arr, len){
    for(let i = 0; i<len; i++){
        if(arr[i] >= largest){
            largest = arr[i];
        }
        if(arr[i] <= smallest){
            smallest = arr[i];
        }
    }
    for(let i = 0; i < len; i++){
        if(arr[i] > smallest){
            maxSum += arr[i];
        }
        if(arr[i] < largest){
            minSum += arr[i];
        }
    }
    return console.log(minSum, maxSum)

}

minMax(arr, len)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

solution in fewest possible lines, i think

'function miniMaxSum(arr) {

```
arr.sort((a,b)=>a-b);
let fSum=0, lSum=0;
for(let x=0; x<arr.length-1; x++){
    fSum+=arr[x]
}
for(let x=1; x<arr.length; x++){
    lSum+=arr[x]
}
console.log(fSum+" "+lSum);
```

}'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).